# Vanilla Javascript use of bind() with REST parameter

Tags: javascript, bind

Why bind() passes even the type of event with rest parameters. How to avoid passing the event 'click'?

```
function say(...numbers) {
  for (const number of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('input_10_5');
  el.addEventListener('click', say.bind(null, 1, 2, 3));
});
```

Console.log result:

```
1
2
3 
click { target: input#input_10_5.medium, buttons: 0, clientX: 1062, clientY: 732, layerX: 96, layerY: 24
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The event handling system always passes the event.

> The callback function itself has the same parameters and return value as the handleEvent() method; that is, the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on Event describing the event that has occurred, and it returns nothing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback

If your goal is to iterate the arguments and treat them all the same then how about:
`function say(numbers, event)`
`say.bind(null, [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it was possible, so I will keep using the array as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior doesn't have to do with rest parameters `...`. It is more to do with the behavior of `.bind()`. When you bind a function with arguments (in this case you've used `1, 2, 3`), calling that bound function causes those bound arguments to be passed to the function *first*, then followed by any additional arguments you call the bound function with, eg:

```js
function foo(one, two, three, evt) {
  console.log(one, two, three, evt);
}

const bar = foo.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);
bar({type: "click"}); // becomes the 4th argument (after 1, 2, 3)
```

Under the hood, JavaScript is calling your bound function that you pass to `.addEventListener()` with the event object, which ends up becoming the fourth argument to your `say` function. This is then included as part of the `numbers` array. You can instead create a wrapper function that gets passed `event` (which you ignore), and then use `.call()` to call your function (using `.call()` here instead of just `()` allows you to explicitly define the `this` value like you're doing with `.bind()`):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('input_10_5');
  el.addEventListener('click', () => say.call(null, 1, 2, 3));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with **a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called**.

You can't prevent `bind` from doing that.

If you don't want that, don't use `bind`.

Just create a new function the traditional way instead.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function () { say(1, 2, 3) });
```